# Prolog Knowledge bases Unification

Tags: prolog

I have to make the following problem in prolog, I have to build the rules:

`recetar_a(X,Y)`, `alivia(X,Y)` and `enfermo_de(X,Y)`

I know my solution for `enfermo_de(X,Y)` works, but I don't know if the solutions for `recetar_a(X,Y)`, `alivia(X,Y)` are correct and I'm confuse, someone help me please how the unification works in these cases? Thanks!

```
enfermo_de(manuel,gripe).

tiene_sintoma(alicia,cansancio).

sintoma_de(fiebre,gripe).
sintoma_de(tos,gripe).
sintoma_de(cansancio,anemia).

elimina(vitaminas,cansancio).
elimina(aspirinas,fiebre).
elimina(jarabe,tos).

recetar_a(X,Y) :- 
    enfermo_de(Y,A),
    alivia(X,A).

alivia(X,Y) :-
    elimina(X,A),
    sintoma_de(A,Y).

enfermo_de(X,Y) :- 
    tiene_sintoma(X,Z),
    sintoma_de(Z,Y).
```

The meanings of each predicates are:

```
  enfermo_de=sickof
  tiene_sintoma=hassymptom
  sintoma_de=symptomof
  elimina=cure
  recetar_a=prescribe
  alivia=relieve
```

Comment: Can you say what `recetar_a`, etc. mean and how they are related?

Comment: Yes, I just edited it in the code above, enfermo_de=sick of
      tiene_sintoma= has symptom
      sintoma_de= symptom of
      elimina=cure
      recetar_a=prescribe
      alivia=relieve

Comment: Why don't you just translate the predicates to English? And a more specific question would be nicer, as in, "I expected unification X to take place, but instead I get Y, why?"